# GNU Libraries- Which Library would have the _POSIX_OPEN_MAX symbol?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, gnu, symbols, limits

I am trying to learn more about Linux on the systemcall/interface level. Starting with limits, I read in APUE that limits such as _POSIX_OPEN_MAX are symbols. After googling, I read these symbols are in libraries. How do I find which library would have the _POSIX_OPEN_MAX symbol? I did find the header files with the limits, but I would like to learn how locate these in the compiled GNU libraries on my Linux System(using nm?). There are so many libraries I would not know where to begin to map out where these symbols would be.

Answer (score 1):

`_POSIX_OPEN_MAX` is a macro and is replaced at compile time. In most cases, all information about macros is discarded after preprocessing, and so there is no symbol as such.

It *is* possible to make `gcc` include information about macros by using the `-gdwarf-2` and `-g3` flags, but it's very unlikely these options were used when building your system libraries. So, in short, you most likely won't find it in any of them.

Comment: This makes sense to me also. But my APUE book calls these symbols when using it's AWK program to detect them in pathconf.sym and sysconf.sym.  (in the limits section 2.5).